# What's the difference between aspectjrt-1.7.1.jar and aspectjweaver-1.7.1.jar，they all have the org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut.class

Tags: java, spring, jar

It really confused me recently.The problem is that my terminal printed  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut`.
Then I searched which jar on the `CLASSPATH` has the class.But I found both `aspectjrt-1.7.1.jar` and `aspectjweaver-1.7.1.jar` have the class.I can't figure out the difference of the two jars. It's a project written by other team. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like aspectjweaver is superset of aspectjrt + few other classes required for load-time weaving (LTW) during class-loading. So mostly if we include aspectjweaver it also has all the classes from aspectjrt so we don't need to include aspectjrt.jar anymore.

Please refer to description of both libraries in maven repository.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt